# Outlook - save/convert email body to PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

I need a macro script to:

1. Convert/Print email body to PDF file
2. Save that file to a folder
3. Delete the email after

I'm pretty clueless on using scripts/macros on outlook. Would need step by step process if possible. I do have adobe program for converting installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the message as a DOC file (OlSaveAsType.olDoc), then use the Word Object Model to convert it to PDF.